# dotnetnuke share content across portals

Tags: dotnetnuke, portal

I'm testing the community version of DNN v 7.0

We have 3 portals. I need to share content across portals, is that possible?  I need to have one source for the content, so when I update it, all pages that have that content get the updated text.
My search for this solution either lands me in really old pages or not-too-clear answers.

Answer (score 1):

DNN 7 introduced cross-site content sharing in the [Professional Edition](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Products/Compare-Editions.aspx) of DotNetNuke.  This is the only "supported" way to achieve what you're trying.

It is possible to write a custom extension which would display the content of a module from another portal, but I'm not aware of any up-to-date solutions which support this right now.

Answer (score 1):

There are several 3rd party solutions that would allow you to share content other portals. Most of our modules have this feature including Live Wrapper, Live Tabs, Live Accordion, Live Content and so forth.

You may want to try Live Wrapper trial to see if it meets your needs. Thanks

http://www.mandeeps.com/products/dotnetnuke-modules/live-wrapper.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Inventua's Shadow module](http://www.inventua.com/Default.aspx?tabid=64&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).